# Forcing Python Toolbox tool to break loop and do cleanup when user clicks Cancel?

Tags: arcpy, python-toolbox, arccatalog, events

I am writing a Python tool that perform heavy tasks in a loop. When the user clicks "Close" I want to break the loop, perform some cleanup, and then finish.

Consider this example tool that counts down from ten:

```
import arcpy
import time

class Tool(object):

   def __init__(self):
      self.label = "Cancel Test"
      self.description = "Tests how the cancel function works."
      self.canRunInBackground = False

   def execute(self, parameters, messages):
      for i in range(10, -1, -1):
         arcpy.AddMessage(i)
         time.sleep(1)
      arcpy.AddMessage("We have lift-off!")
      return
```

When I click "Close" in the beginning of the execution it does not brake the loop or give me an opportunity to perform any clean up. Instead it loops to the very end and adds the message `"We have lift-off!"` before it outputs this:

```
Completed script CancelTest...
Cancelled function
(CancelTest) aborted by User.
Failed at [TIME] (Elapsed Time: 10,01 seconds)
```

I have found [documentation](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/geoprocessing_and_python/understanding-cancellation-behavior-in-script-tools.htm) for ArcGIS Pro (that uses Python 3.4) that describes how you can do this there using `isCancelled`:

```
import arcpy
import time

#Make sure it does not auto cancel.
arcpy.env.autoCancelling = False

class Tool(object):

   def __init__(self):
      self.label = "Cancel Test"
      self.description = "Tests how the cancel function works."
      self.canRunInBackground = False

   def execute(self, parameters, messages):
      for i in range(10, -1, -1):
         arcpy.AddMessage(i)
         time.sleep(1)
         #Check if the user clicked "Close"
         if arcpy.env.isCancelled:
            arcpy.AddMessage("Launch aborted!")
            return
      arcpy.AddMessage("We have lift-off!")
      return
```

However, when I run this from ArcCatalog 10.3 (i.e. not using ArcGIS Pro) it gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\Mina Dokument\DGD\Python\CancelTest.py", line 19, in execute
    if arcpy.env.isCancelled:
AttributeError: 'GPEnvironment' object has no attribute 'isCancelled'
```

Is there anyway to mimic the behavior that is available in ArcGIS Pro in an ordinary Python toolbox using Python 2.7?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Farid Cher's answer is partially correct.

You can use the Progressor to 'catch' a cancel event from within a Python script, and you can also do whatever cleanup necessary as well, if you enclose the call within a `try ... except` clause.

For example, a python toolbox:

```
import arcpy
import time

class Toolbox(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.label = "Toolbox"
        self.alias = ""
        self.tools = [Tool]


class Tool(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.label = "Tool"
        self.description = ""
        self.canRunInBackground = False

    def execute(self, parameters, messages):
        some_stuff = [] # a variable to cleanup later
        max = 1000
        arcpy.SetProgressor('step','Testing ArcPy script cancel',0,max,1)

        # You don't have to be in a for loop, but this is the
        # easiest way to show an example
        for i in range(max):
            try: 
                # only put SetProgressorPosition in this clause
                # otherwise you can catch other errors that aren't
                # the user cancelling
                arcpy.SetProgressorPosition()
            except:
                arcpy.AddWarning('User canceled at i = {0}'.format(i))
                del some_stuff # cleanup
                return
            time.sleep(0.1)
            some_stuff.append(i)
        arcpy.AddMessage('User did not cancel')
        del some_stuff
```

This allows the user to run the tool:
[image: before cancel]

And then cancel, which is handled gracefully (and still counted as a failed run):
[image: after cancel]

*edit:* This doesn't appear to work with 10.3 or ArcGIS Pro.

To catch the cancels (tested in ArcGIS Pro), we bring back our good friend `arcgisscripting`. This is similar to catching the cancel from the progressor, but the entire execute function, or at least the majority of it, needs to be inside the `try`:

```
import arcpy
import arcgisscripting
import time

class Toolbox(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.label = "Toolbox"
        self.alias = ""
        self.tools = [Tool]


class Tool(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.label = "Tool"
        self.description = ""
        self.canRunInBackground = False

    def execute(self, parameters, messages):
        try:
            some_stuff = []
            max = 1000
            arcpy.SetProgressor('step','Testing ArcPy script cancel',0,max,1)

            for i in range(max):
                arcpy.SetProgressorPosition()
                time.sleep(0.1)
                some_stuff.append(i)
        except arcgisscripting.ExecuteAbort:
            arcpy.AddWarning('User cancelled at i={0}'.format(i))
            del some_stuff
            return
        arcpy.AddMessage('User did not cancel')
        del some_stuff
```

[image: before cancel in pro]

[image: after cancel in pro]

Comment: Indeed, this is a good alternative to bypass if `arcpy.env.isCancelled`.

Comment: +1 @Evil Genius,  I didn't think of a try...catch. Good workaround. Thanks for expansion.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Strangely enough, your code does not behave the same way when I run it as when you run it. If I press "Cancel" it does break the loop, but it does not print `User canceled at i =`. Also tested creating a file (in case there was some strange problem with the message printing) but it looks like the `except` clasue do not run. I am using ArcGIS 10.3 and running the tool from ArcCatalog, no ArcGIS Pro involved. What version are you running?

Comment: @Anders Odd. I'm using 10.2.1. It's possible that it changed with 10.3, although this method has worked since 9.3. Did you do just the example code or modify your own? Do you have any other `try` clauses going on that would be catching it somewhere?

Comment: @EvilGenius I confirm that it doens't behave as you have showed in your snapshots! Just like Andres mentions.(I use 10.2.2)

Comment: @FaridCher How strange. It sounds like 10.3 acts just as ArcGIS Pro does, although the environment variables aren't available.

Comment: Anders & @FaridCher please see the edit! Unfortunately I can't test 10.3, but I did test it with ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: @EvilGenius Yup, copy-pasted your code. It is all very strange. However, your new code with `arcgisscripting` seems to work like a charm! Thanks a lot! I will take some time to verify that it do in fact work, and then award the bounty.

Comment: I've tested it more thouroughly now, and it does indeed work on 10.3! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Your message is clear:

```
AttributeError: 'GPEnvironment' object has no attribute 'isCancelled'
```

In fact `arcpy.env.autoCancelling` and `arcpy.env.isCancelled` are added in Arcgis Pro 1.1 (planned for ArcGIS 10.4)

Furthermore, if you use Arcgis 10.3, these features are not available.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you know if they will be added in only ArcGIS Pro? Or will they be added "everywhere" in ArcGIS 10.4, so just eventually upgrading to 10.4 but still not use Pro would solve it? And do you have any reference for this information? Thanks.

Comment: yep. You can look at [arpy env object](https://desktop.arcgis.com/fr/desktop/latest/analyze/arcpy-classes/env.htm) **isCancelled** doent exist in last version desktop (10.3.1) but  [arcpy env object](https://pro.arcgis.com/fr/pro-app/arcpy/classes/env.htm)  exist in last version pro (1.1.1) . You can look this at [Whats news in Arc GIS Pro](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/get-started/whats-new-in-arcgis-pro.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_75148D0B50BA4C73B453504D277FD573)  . There is also [this project who speak about it](https://github.com/ghisprince/arcpy-cpp-interop)

Comment: @Anders  If it's necessary for you to use isCancel you need to bypass python env and use an interop solution in desktop. Alternatively, you can use it now if you use ArcGIS Pro

Answer (score 2):

The closest way that I can think of is the use of Progressor in Arcpy. Using progressor, once the user press the cancel button the loop breaks and the execution terminates. However you can not do any cleanup! Here is a sample code:

```
def execute(self, parameters, messages):
    import time
    n=10
    p=1
    arcpy.SetProgressor("step",
                        "Step progressor: Counting from 0 to {0}".format(n),
                        0, n, p)
    loopTime=.3
    for i in range(n):
        if (i % p) == 0:
            ## put your custom code here
            ## it will break the loop if the user cancels. and the tool execution terminates
            arcpy.SetProgressorLabel("Iteration: {0}".format(i))
            arcpy.SetProgressorPosition(i)
            time.sleep(loopTime)

    arcpy.AddMessage("You will not get here to do cleanup if the loop terminates prematurelly")
    arcpy.SetProgressorLabel("Iteration finished: {0}".format(i + 1))
    arcpy.SetProgressorPosition(i + 1)

    return
```

**Update (To answer the questions in the comment):**

> why using a progressor changes how the program behaves, other than
>   adding a nice looking progress bar?

The progressor is a kind of multi-thread processing. each time the progressor steps forward, the GUI (a separate thread) must be updated. While using a progressor, you are running your code in another inline thread. However it is not definitely like Background geo-processing in which you can run multiple thread simultaneously.

> Does using a progressor make ArcGIS brake the code when the user press
>   "Cancel"?

Yes, note that the breaking happens in the loop, where you are updating your progress bar (e.g. like the example above)

> where does it break? Is it directly after whatever line it happens to
>   be at when the button is pressed?

The breaking happens between any two progress steps that the user clicks the cancel button. In the above code example its:

```
if (i % p) == 0:
            ## put your custom code here
            ## it will break the loop if the user cancels. and the tool execution terminates
            arcpy.SetProgressorLabel("Iteration: {0}".format(i))
```

If the user click `cancel`, your custom code will be executed until it reaches `arcpy.SetProgressorLabel("Iteration: {0}".format(i))`. This is where the gp tool will get notified of the cancel event (e.g. kill the separate inline thread)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Not sure I understand how and why using a progressor changes how the program behaves, other than adding a nice looking progress bar? Does using a progressor make ArcGIS brake the code when the user press "Close"? In that case, where does it brake? Is it directly after whatever line it happens to be at when the button is pressed?

Comment: You're welcome. @Anders, see the updated answer.

Comment: @FaridCher I explain why it can't work with`isCancelled` but indeed, `SetProgressor` is a good alternative to bypass`arcpy.env.isCancelled`

Comment: When I run your code, it behaves as designed. The counter stops, and no cleanup is done. However, if I add `arcpy.AddMessage(i)` between `SetProgressorPosition` and `sleep` in the loop, suddenly it runs through the whole loop and the cleanup. Any idea to why that may be? It makes me feel a bit confused...

Comment: @Anders, huh, very funny behavior. I can't figure out how the ESRI enginer has written the Progressor Class!!

Comment: If you are equally confused I think we can write it off as ESRI being strange. Thanks for all the help!